# When, if ever, does space created by \hspace get expanded?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I have been using the following pattern to allow a date in MM/DD/YYYY format to be broken after each solidus.

```
01/\hspace{0pt}/01\hspace{0pt}/2001
```

I never want extra space after the solidus; I want it to be translated into either a line break or nothing (the equivalent of "no-width optional break" as applied in MS Word, I believe). But does the **TeX** system allow additional space to be inserted? Should I be using a different pattern to allow for optional line breaks?

If I enter the date as

```
01/01/2001
```

there are cases when its rendered form violates the margin.

Comment: You could try `\allowbreak`.

Comment: `\hspace{0pt}` ultimately expands to `\hskip 0pt\relax` which has no stretch nor shrink.

Answer (score 8):

A skip (hspace) with any amount of stretch will over stretch if the surrounding box has not enough content to fill its width, this is the infamous "underfull hbox" warning. However a skip with no stretch or shrink component as in your example is never stretched.

That said, you do not want to have a space here, so using `\hspace` just to allow line breaking as a side effect is not the best markup, you could use

```
01/\linebreak[0]01
```

which adds a penalty of 0 allowing, but neither encouraging or discouraging a break, or use the provided macro

```
01\slash 01
```

which uses the same penalty as an explicit hyphen which (in most classes) allows, but mildly discourages, a break there.

Or you could use the `url` package and

```
 \DeclareUrlCommand\mydate{\urlstyle{relax}}
 \mydate{01/01/2017}
```

as that package allows line breaking on `/` (the `relax` just says to do nothing about switching fonts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `01/\penalty0{}01/\penalty0{}2001`

`\penalty0` allows easy break.

Comment: See @DavidCarlisle’s answer; `/\penalty\exhyphenpenalty` is better, because it rates the break as a break at a hyphen, and is exactly what `\slash` expands to.